# Adding captions to a video clip (preferably on MAC OS)

Tags: video-editing

I'm creating a scientific video clip for a conference, and I need to add captions to the movie. So,
**How can I add caption to a video?**

Here are some more details:

- I'm working on either `mac os` or `linux`, so I would be happier to have tools and solutions not involving `windows`.
- The video size is not standard (as it is a product of concatenation of images) - so, trying out `iMovie` didn't help. Although it can very well be that I missed something there.
- Googling for a solution yielded somehow outdated, or irrelevant results.
- Adding `LaTeX` like text in the captions would be a wonderful benefit for me.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit 1:

Two clarifications:

- The resulting video should be one file (some standard format) - that is the captions should be "burned" into the movie.
- By "caption"s I mean text of arbitrary size, in arbitrary position on the frame. Thus, "subtitles" is not what I'm after.

Comment: Load it in iMovie and add some text?

Comment: @SimonSheehan as I wrote; I tried iMovie, but it won't work, as each frame's size is *not* standard, and thus iMovie cuts it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about LaTeX on video, but if you're fine with plain text a subtitle editing program might be worth looking into. [Here's one for Macs](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25826/subs-factory). Of course, your video player would have to support subtitles, and the subtitle format would have to be compatible. They're somewhat standard, but better be sure before really getting into it. Some subtitle editors let you embed them as part of the video, but I'm not sure about such a program for Mac.

Good luck.